# Star Wars Jedi Challenge (AR): How do I dodge?

Tags: star-wars-jedi-challenges

[Star Wars Jedi Challenge](https://www.lenovo.com/au/en/jedichallenges/) (AR)

This is killing me. To dodge is to move or lean in the direction of premonition, which is where the game points to move. The game says 'move' while the woman who is Kylo Ren's trainer or something says 'lean'.

1. How is it done exactly?

Is it a strafe? A lean? Both?

[This guy](https://youtu.be/Q8c4hDbsoqc?t=284) does it so easily: a simple step/[strafe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strafing_(gaming)) and no leaning in the direction. I have tried stepping/strafing but no leaning, leaning but no stepping /strafing and both stepping/strafing and leaning.

[Later](https://youtu.be/Q8c4hDbsoqc?t=408), he leans and does not step.

2. How is the space of the playing area related?

I think I am a little limited by the sofa in the room, but I have dodged successfully a few times.

3. Is there an option to practice dodging?

The only practice, it seems, is when dodging is first introduced. It took me a lot of tries to finally dodge, and I have no idea how I did it.

---

Of course this could be an error/bug/whatchamacallit since AR is relatively new  or something. Idk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually e-mailed them, but their answer didn't work out for me.

Partial answer:

To compensate for dodging,

1. use sith abilities
2. Improve blocks. In particular, use both hands to quickly shift from one block to another, especially against Rey.